# node.js/ io processing what fixes in?

Tags: jquery, node.js

So this is just the design phase and i wished to know how can this be implemented. I need to access a csv file at server side and validate it. This csv file will have more than 50,000 records and while validating each row in the csv I want to show a UI to user saying 1 of 50000 processing... 2 of 50000 processing .. and so on.

Is there any suggestion to implement the IO display? I have already written Java code for my server side validation that validates both the csv headers and csv content reading csv row by row.

Can i use node.js or http://jslib.mozdev.org/ http://dojotoolkit.org/.

I can use jsp + jquery at client side. Currently I am just making a ajax call to the java code and traversing the csv file. What if i want to show a progress UI to user?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://socket.io and emit events from server app when you want to inform about the progress. As far as UI rendering, take a look in bootstrap. it has a lot of UI elements to make animated progress bars etc.

Comment: Thank you Biba. I am already using Boostrap. So with socket.io do you suggest me to handle some part of opening the file and sending each row one by one to the java side for validation ?

Comment: No, if i understand correctly you are doing all validation server side, you just want to inform the UI of the progress. Hence, you emit a status event as often as you like from your validation loop in java, say: every 1000 validated files you say Emitevent("progress", {current: 1000, total: 1000000} so then the UI can say 1%. its not clear to me if the csv file is already on the server or it's still on the client and you're uploading or so. I assumed it's on the server already.

Comment: okay i get what you are saying. Well file at server side is better. Let me try Emitevent property and see if that helps. Thank you for elaborating. If there is anything else that works better pls let me know. anyhting scalable. non i/o blockable

Comment: Definitely move the file to the server OR, use the server to read the file from remote location such as dropbox or so. The point is, for performance reasons don't send in "chunked" number of rows to the server from the client side. the network round trips and the chance to suffer a temporary disconnect are far too great to have a reliable and usable implementation. If you only need to validate few attributes from the CSV content, then you can have a function in the API that takes a bulk JSON array with JUST the document ids and the properties that need validated.

Comment: this way you can call once for every X numbers of rows that suits you say 1000. If the number of columns to be validated exceeds 50% of them you'd be better off uploading the file to the server ;-)

Comment: Yes, i am keeping the file at server side. But the challenge that I am facing is with giving the user a status like "1 of 1000 processed" "2 of 1000 processed" and so on.. still figuring that thing out.

Comment: As best practice you should give the user status in chunks, or batches of 100 or 1000 or so. Communicating processing status from server to client over a disconnected or seldomly connected architecture (web) will be a performance killer. Make a pragmatism call and ask yourself: is it really really useful if the user knows with precision if it's 435,298 or 435,000 to of 1,000,000 total have been processed any given 10 seconds or so.